# IIS rewrite working as redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, iis-7, url-rewriting

What i understand about Url rewriting and redirect is (please point out my wrong assumptions)

- by using "redirect" option for url
  `http://localhost/Search/VehicleDetails.aspx?id=2` to transform it
  into  `http://localhost/Search/2/VehicleDetails.aspx`,when client
  browse `http://localhost/Search/VehicleDetails.aspx?id=2` and our
  redirect rule changes into
  `http://localhost/Search/2/VehicleDetails.aspx`,the server tries to
  find VehicleDetails.aspx page inside `/Search/2` folder.
- but by using "rewrite" option for url
  `http://localhost/Search/VehicleDetails.aspx?id=2` to transform it
  into `http://localhost/Search/2/VehicleDetails.aspx`,when client
  browse `http://localhost/Search/VehicleDetails.aspx?id=2`, client
  browser displays `http://localhost/Search/2/VehicleDetails.aspx` ,but
  internally in server request is made in VehicleDetails.aspx page of
  Search directory ,not in VehicleDetails.aspx of /Search/2
  directory...

and my problem is ,i tried to rewrite url by following rule

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Search" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^.*(?:Search/VehicleDetails.aspx).*$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=(\d+)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/Search/{C:1}/VehicleDetails.aspx" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

it redirects to `/Search/2/VehicleDetails.aspx` page with  `HTTP 404.(The resource cannot be found.)`.I want that client browser shows `http://localhost/Search/2/VehicleDetails.aspx` but request is made on `/Search/VehicleDetails.aspx`..

And also how do i get values of id (2 in this example) for the url like

`http://localhost/Search/2/VehicleDetails.aspx` by Request.QueryString["id"]??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the `Append QueryString` checkbox in IIS or add this manually, for example: -

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="/Search/{C:1}/VehicleDetails.aspx" 
redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
```

I noticed you have this set to `False` which will be why the ID is not being carried over and is probably the reason for the 404 too.

Comment: thanx for your quick respone.I also figured out that redirectType="Permanent" option is valid for type="Redirect" and removed it,but it doesn't work :(..and can u also clarify my query on rewriting and redirect difference.. is my assumption right??